# How to fix Div overlapping?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a situation with X number of divs as below:

```
"<div style="position: absolute; left: 327.507px; top: 42.3433px;" class="point-label">25.49</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 323.738px; top: 60.8532px;" class="point-label">21.04</div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 322.821px; top: 64.6363px;" class="point-label">20.14</div>"
.
.
.
```

They have auto-generated fixed positions which I can't do much about it. The problem is sometimes they overlapp, look at the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rawand/WswD3/

The question is: can the overlap be solved by CSS? otherwise by javascript?
I want them to be placed above eath other with minimum position changes possible, as in the image link: i.stack.imgur.com/xbqHI.jpg

Comment: can you add classes to the objects?  Whatever is autogenerating the positions is doing a bad job

Comment: Just to let you know that you shouldn't have a decimal value of a pixel

Comment: I guess you need to keep the absolute position....for some reason I think about a map with coordinates. You need a better JS function to do that job. @KonstantinTarkus I don't think the problem is about z-index I guess he wants to avoid at all the overlap.

Comment: have a google for javascript div collision detection, there are plenty of solutions out there

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WswD3/1/)?

Comment: What is auto generating them and how should they be displayed?

Comment: @Rondles I added an image link to how I would want them, I want the numbers to be visible with minimum position changes possible.its jqplot that generating them on a chart.

Comment: I've put an answer up that sort of gives you what you want, but more vertically aligned (your top element in your picture is out of alignment, not sure if this is intentional or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you, I guess you can change the position of DIVs using Jquery

for example set a class 'p1'

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 327.507px; top: 42.3433px;" class="point-label p1">25.49</div>
```

then :

```
$('.p1').each(function(){
    $(this).next('div').css({'left' : parseInt($(this).css('left')) + parseInt($(this).css('width')) + 'px'})
});
```

Comment: I quite like this. It's like a staircase of divs.

Comment: Is there a way i can do that only for overlapping divs? e.g. if difference between 'top' of 2 divs is less than 10px, then add 10px to the top position?

Comment: you can change the DIVs you are looping over by changing the selector of the '$.each', ie '.point-label' instead of '.p1'.
you can get the height of each div and add 10px to it.
may be you mean like this : http://jsfiddle.net/WswD3/13/

Comment: That's a good solution and from what @user3228036 said to me I think that may be what he requires. Although ideally the thing generating the HTML in the first place needs fixing.

Comment: This adds 15px if the difference is less than 10px :
http://jsfiddle.net/WswD3/15/
accept the answer if it helped you :)
@Rondles thaks

Comment: Thanks @Rabi, its the sort of answer i was looking for

Answer (score -1):

I would submit this as a comment (but can't due to lack of rep). Follow what Ravi says and I wouldn't use decimals with pixels, instead use decimals with ems, rems and percentages.

Comment: Using Ravi's technique leads to further spacing issues, see my reply to his answer and the fiddle I've done to demonstrate this.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a javascript solution to line them up. It's not particularly elegant, and could be done in a simpler fashion in jQuery, but it stops them overlapping and makes them somewhat uniform.

http://jsfiddle.net/WswD3/7/

```
function removeAtt(){
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("point-label");

    for(i in elems){
        elems[i].removeAttribute("style");
        elems[i].style.position = "relative";
        elems[i].style.left = "323px";
    }
}

removeAtt();
```

Comment: Thanks Rondles for the answer, but I dont want to reposition them, because the website is dynamic and I cant hardcode any position.

Comment: @user3228036 Ok then. Not quite sure exactly what you want to achieve as using position absolute is essentially hardcoding a position in terms of CSS. If you figure this out please post the answer here as I am interested in seeing what you want to achieve and how you do it. Thanks.